# Nginx encountered this kind of loading certificate error, how to solve it?

Tags: nginx

Nginx encountered this kind of loading certificate error, how to solve it?

> 2019/03/14 14:48:11 [emerg] 11496#5252: cannot load certificate
>   "C:\Users\Alan\Downloads\nginx-1.15.9/conf/localhost.csr":
>   PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM
>   routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)

I want to implement HTTPS locally.

Where is the configuration wrong?

I am using the ssl certificate generated by openssl.

Comment: Looking at the file extension, this is the Certificate Signing Request and not the actual certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Your file extension should be `.crt` or `.cer`, not `.csr` (Ex. wildcart.crt).